# Stream audio over network in MP3

Tags: c#

My question is simple,

I would like to do this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19854/Sending-and-playing-microphone-audio-over-network

But with another codec , in MP3.

Its possible with a free SDK/tools ... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/) can stream in a variety of different formats, including [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/). I have not used them myself, but it looks like a nice starting point.

Comment: Thanks, almost a useful answer. In fact, i didn't know that VLC has a library for dev in .net

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the NAudio library and send the buffer with sockets (which should be easy since they're both a byte array).

I can't expend too much because NAudio and sockets are 2 complete subjects.
But I can provide links:

**NAudio**

- [Any information you'd probably need + download can be found here](http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation)
- [The videos in this user is a nice series that explains NAudio](http://www.youtube.com/user/GiawaVideos?feature=watch)

**Sockets** - pretty hard subject for me so I'll give more links

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspxhttp://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/sampleprograms/article.php/c7695/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-I.htm
- http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5252/Sockets-in-C
- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/
- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/sampleprograms/article.php/c7695/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-I.htm
- http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-socket-programming.htm

Don't forget to use Google!
Once you have basic understanding read my first sentence (with the buffer) and it will be clear.

P.S. NAudio might need another .dll to handle mp3, not sure, but it shouldn't be hard to find.